# How to Import an Android Gradle Project from Windows to Linux using Intellij without getting keystore issues

Tags: java, android, linux, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I am currently trying to import an Android libgdx project from my Windows desktop to my Linux laptop.  The project has a keystore I use for generating the release builds of the app.  I pulled the project down from github, but when I try to import it to the Linux computer, Intellij tries to find the keystore at the location it is on the Windows computer, and can't.  Is there a way to change where Intellij looks for the file, or get it to ignore the keystore on the Linux computer without affecting the Windows build.gradle file? Or do I need to generate a new build.gradle for the Linux computer specifically? (I don't need to be able to generate release signed apks on the Linux computer)

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

manually port the keystore from WIN to LNX then make corresponding change to build.gradle.android TAG....

signingConfigs {
    release {

```
    storeFile file("/home/$youUser/keys/keystore/android")
    storePassword "whatisit"
    keyAlias "yourkey"
    keyPassword "your2ndkey"
}
```

}